# Handling date time range in django view

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement date time range in django. But I've no idea, how to implement properly.
Here I'm using html forms.
[image]

From the django view I'm requesting value like this.

```
date_time_range = request.POST.get('date_time_range')
```

expected outpul: [2020-01-31 09:03:11.161574, 2020-01-31 09:03:11.161574]

actual outpul: 02/09/2020 12:00 AM - 02/09/2020 11:59 PM

My actual scenario: Actually I want to start and stop task

Comment: Pass it in the form that you used to interpret the result into a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired results by parsing and again formatting your date like this:

```
datetime.strptime("02/09/2020 12:00 AM", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s")
```

So in your case, you should do something like below:

```
date_time_range = request.POST.get('date_time_range')

result = [datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s") for d in date_time_range.split(' - ')]
```